# Orange Outline Glitch

Tags: modeling

I don't know how but this glitch occured when I launched the Blender. I tried everything that I know but, didn't work. Do you have a solution for this? Thanks.

[image: ss]

Comment: Hello :). Make sure your GPU Drivers are up to date and your hardware meets the minimum requirements. Other than that, you can try an older version :).

Comment: My older PC had exactly this problem, was due to an old graphics card.  See this technical note:  https://developer.blender.org/T75826